# Conditional Props in React (ACCEPT only 1 of 2 props)

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I had a search bar component in react and I wanted to have either an `onSubmit` prop to it or an `onChange` prop, but not both of them together. How do I implement it in the best way possible?

I tried using `if-else` statements but the code doesn't look elegant to me.

```
class QueryBar extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { placeholder, leftIcon, onSubmit, onChange, width } = this.props;
    return (
      <form
        style={{ width }}
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          onSubmit(e.target[0].value);
        }}
      >
        <InputGroup
          placeholder={placeholder}
          width={width}
          leftIcon="search"
          rightElement={
            <Button
              type="submit"
              icon={leftIcon}
              minimal={true}
              intent={Intent.PRIMARY}
            />
          }
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

QueryBar.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.number,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  leftIcon: PropTypes.oneOfType(['string', 'element']),
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func
};

QueryBar.defaultProps = {
  placeholder: 'Search...',
  leftIcon: 'arrow-right',
  width: 360
};
export default QueryBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator (?) instead of if-else.

```
const { placeholder, leftIcon, onSubmit, onChange, width } = this.props;
const handleSubmit = onSubmit ? onSubmit : onChange;
```

And use the same function later

```
<form
    style={{ width }}
    onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSubmit(e.target[0].value);
    }}
>
```

Comment: the problem here is that the form will have an onChange field, not the onSubmit, if the onChange prop is passed

Comment: @malikbagwala are you saying it will have onChange attribute instead of onSubmit attribute?

Comment: yes..it will have an onChange attribute instead of onSubmit